# JGit Connection refused

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'd like to clone remote repository, add file and push file back but getting exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git://192.168.1.1/abc: Connection refused: connect
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.fetch(CloneCommand.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CloneCommand.call(CloneCommand.java:125)
```

Code is:

```
UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider user = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userId, userPass);
File workingCopy = new File(REPO_PATH);
Git.cloneRepository().setCredentialsProvider(user).setURI(uri).setDirectory(workingCopy).setBranch("master").setBare(false).setRemote("origin").setNoCheckout(false).call();
```

Now remote repo is on localhost, and when I use "localhost" in path everything works fine and when use IP address I'm getting exception like above. Port 9418 is unlocked.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: your computer does not know that 192.168.1.1 is localhost. May be you wanted to say "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: No, I don't, thanks. I'd like to use network address.

Comment: can you ping 192.168.1.1 or better yet telnet on that port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get a "Connection Refused" error message, that (normally) means that no service was listening on IP address + port that your client was trying to connect to.

A common trick for confirming this problem is using some other utility to attempt to connects to the problem IP + port.  The `telnet` utility is commonly used for this.  Install it (if necessary) and check the manual entry to find the command line options for specifying the port number.  (It will depend on your OS ...)

Given that you say that localhost works, and the port you are using is not blocked by your local firewall, the most likely explanation is that you have only configured your Git server software to listen on the `localhost` IP address (typically `127.0.0.1`)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to set a credentials provider for git protocol since it's anonymous